# Kali Linux Install Issue

Tags: linux, kali-linux, debian-installer

Yesterday I tried to install Kali Linux in my laptop. The installation succeeds and ask to remove installer cd/dvd/external drive at the end. But after that when I boot from Kali it starts installation process again. I continue installation 2 more times, but same issue continues.

I am very confused about the issue.

**My Laptop Configuration**

- Intel pentium dual core processor.
- 2GB RAM
- 320 GB Hard disk
- Windows 7 installed in C: drive
- I have another 3 Drives of 71GB each D:,E:,F:
- I am installing Kali on F: drive.
- I created a root partition, a boot partition and swap partition

At my boot screen I can see 2 Operating Systems:

- 1- Windows 7
- 2- Debian Linux installer

Comment: Tell me... When the installer tells you to **remove the installation media (CD/DVD/USB/...)**... do you do it? There's no way the BIOS could possibly boot onto the installer if you've indeed removed the drive on which it is burnt.

Comment: At my Boot Screen I can see 2 Operating System 1- Windows 7, 2- Desbian Linux installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some issue with boot loader.

The GRUB is not loaded properly.

And installation is not finished.

Answer (score -1):

Try running [BootRepair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/). You should burn it to a disk and then hit F12 as you restart. Boot from bootrepair disk and that should solve your issue. I run windows 10 with kali as my main OS.